# Quais são as principais linguagens de programação e e kits de desenvolvimento da aplicações móveis ?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone

Olá pessoal no cenário de desenvolvimento mobile quais seriam as principais tecnologias e kits de desenvolvimento e linguagem de programação para desenvolver sistemas em sistemas operacionais **IOS** , **ANDROID**, e **Windows phone?** ?

Comment: Dê uma lida no [tour], no [ask] e no http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask Ou seja.a além da pergunta ser ampla, ela não é relevante, ela não resolve problema algum. Se você quer saber algo específico, se tem um problema real, prepare uma pergunta nesses moldes. Isto é apenas curiosidade.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link : https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjADahUKEwio_Ma16dHHAhVCQpAKHd0cC9w&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibertas1.sslblindado.com%2Frevistalibertas%2Fdownloadpdf.php%3Fr%3Drevistalibertas1%2Fartigo8&ei=ZX_jVei1O8KEwQTduazgDQ&usg=AFQjCNF-zz9tOc0bJCKOxNSA3G9bzJlOoQ&sig2=Aagfw0H4MJ6Sl873w8LZFw ele faz o download de um pdf que  faz comparação entre algumas IDEs

Comment: Também dê uma pesquisada sobre Phonegap nesse link: https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAAahUKEwjPnP_V79HHAhXElZAKHSmYBCo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphonegap.com%2F&ei=9IXjVc_SJcSrwgSpsJLQAg&usg=AFQjCNG1ra7Js9Qo6QGHtSOloIx4qGEnOA&sig2=Rs9EOC77A1TOnT6CYKiFuA